# Cannnot run a .sh file in terminator

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am having trouble running a `.sh` script file in `Terminator`, however I can run it perfectly fine in the default terminal Ubuntu comes with(gnome-terminal).

This is what I get when trying to run it in terminator:

```
senpai@senpai:~$ '/home/senpai/Documents/Stuff/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh
> 
> '
bash: /home/senpai/Documents/Stuff/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh

: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Run find ~/Documents -type f -name "ts3client_runscript.sh" | xargs sh -c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem in the whitespace(space ,tabs , Enter, whatever...) added to the name of the script.

And here obviously you press enter

I'll show you in example using terminator in my system:

```
$ '/home/maythux/Documents/ts3client_runscript.sh'
Outpout
```

While when running:

```
$ '/home/maythux/Documents/ts3client_runscript.sh
> 
> '
bash: /home/maythux/Documents/ts3client_runscript.sh

: No such file or directory
```

So all you have is to remove those whitespaces(enter in your case)

```
'/home/senpai/Documents/Stuff/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh'
```

Comment: You are welcome, If you like my answer, just click the little grey ☑ under the "0" now turning it into  green

Comment: There are no spaces. See my answer ;)

Comment: Your answer same as mine :) Spaces is not just a space , includes enter and tabs, maybe i have some problem in English but that what i meant

Comment: Ok you're right +1

Comment: The general term is "whitespace", @A.B., but *space* does just as well.

Comment: @muru yeah I'm not native English, I'll correct it